# Getting class probabilities p(c|x) for each data point using sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, probability

How can we get the class probability of each test data point? There are some classifiers that do contain "predict_proba()" function that returns the probability of the data class the data point belongs to.

But there is no such function defined in the https://sklearn-lvq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rslvq.html#

I need to calculate the class probabilities of each class so that the reject option can be applied. The idea is to calculate p(c|x) and check if the value is less than the threshold, then the data point should be rejected.

Comment: Could be better to ask on crossvalidated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Quick clarification: The documentation you linked is to a "*scikit-learn-compatible*" project, not "*scikit-learn*." The authors may not have implemented a `predict_proba` method if there isn't a probabilistic interpretation of the method. In this case it might be best to contact the authors of the package directly (by email or opening up an issue on the GitHub repository).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
**Method 1:** overriding the predict function as follows

```
from sklearn_lvq import RslvqModel
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils import validation
import numpy as np

class RslvqModel_custom(RslvqModel):

    def predict(self, x):
        """Predict class membership index for each input sample.

        This function does classification on an array of
        test vectors X.


        Parameters
        ----------
        x : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]


        Returns
        -------
        C : array, shape = (n_samples,)
            Returns predicted values.
        """
        check_is_fitted(self, ['w_', 'c_w_'])
        x = validation.check_array(x)
        if x.shape[1] != self.w_.shape[1]:
            raise ValueError("X has wrong number of features\n"
                             "found=%d\n"
                             "expected=%d" % (self.w_.shape[1], x.shape[1]))

        def foo(e):
            fun = np.vectorize(lambda w: self._costf(e, w),
                               signature='(n)->()')
            pred = fun(self.w_)
            return pred

        predictions = np.vectorize(foo, signature='(n)->(n)')(x)
        sum = np.sum(predictions, axis=1).reshape(predictions.shape[0], 1)
        return predictions/sum

np.random.seed(1)
print(__doc__)
nb_ppc = 100
x = np.append(
    np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], np.eye(2) / 2, size=nb_ppc),
    np.random.multivariate_normal([5, 0], np.eye(2) / 2, size=nb_ppc), axis=0)
y = np.append(np.zeros(nb_ppc), np.ones(nb_ppc), axis=0)

rslvq = RslvqModel_custom(initial_prototypes=[[5,0,0],[0,0,1]]) #_custom
model = rslvq.fit(x, y)
predictions = model.predict([[3.67, 6.50], [4.97, 1.49], [1.14, -4.3]])

print('============================================================')
print('Predictions: ', predictions)
print('-------------------------------------------------------------')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Predictions:  [[0.5977081  0.4022919 ]
 [0.945568   0.054432  ]
 [0.33533978 0.66466022]]
```

**Method 2:** Or you can simply make use of builtin posterior method:

```
for data in [[3.67, 6.50], [4.97, 1.49], [1.14, -4.3]]:
    print('Class 0:  posterior: ', model.posterior(0, data))
    print('Class 1:  posterior: ', model.posterior(1, data))
    print('='*100)

OUTPUT:

-------------------------------------------------------------
Class 0:  posterior:  [[0.5977081]]
Class 1:  posterior:  [[0.4022919]]
========================================================
Class 0:  posterior:  [[0.945568]]
Class 1:  posterior:  [[0.054432]]
========================================================
Class 0:  posterior:  [[0.33533978]]
Class 1:  posterior:  [[0.66466022]]
========================================================
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing these methods. Well, I am a bit confused with Method 2. The built-in posterior method does not return the probabilities, but a ratio.  "return s1 / s2"

Are these outcomes really the class probabilities?